# How to send byte array as a whole without specifying each element in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, byte

Here I have a byte array as follows:

```
as := []byte{0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00}
```

and the following statement is where I place the variable`as`.

```
    if err := gopacket.SerializeLayers(buffer, options, ethernetLayer, pppoe, gopacket.Payload{as[0], as[1], as[2], as[3]}); err != nil {
        pppoeLogger.Error("serialize-error")
    }
```

this is the `gopacket.Payload` type:

```
type Payload []byte
```

I have tried different things like sending the array as follows:

```
// it does not work obviously. 
gopacket.Payload{as...}
```

Is there an easier way to send the byte array without specifying each element?

Comment: If the two types have the same **underlying type**, then you can use a [conversion expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions): `gopacket.Payload(as)`

Comment: Could you be more specific? It didn't work.

Comment: `gopacket.Payload(as)` works if the types are as you claim in your question. If the expression doesn't work, please provide a [mcve] so we can try help you with an actual issue.

Comment: Ok, now i created as follows: `anyService := gopacket.Payload{0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00}` when I passed this, it worked. However, I need to pass another byte array to  like `gopacket.Payload(anyService, host-uniq)`. In this case it does not accept more than one.

Comment: In fact, if `gopacket.SerializeLayers` corresponding parameter type is truly `gopacket.Payload` and that type is declared as `type Payload []byte` and if the `as` variable's type is `[]byte` then you shouldn't even need conversion because assignment works if the two types have the same underlying type and at least **one of the two** types is unnamed, and `[]byte` is an unnamed type. So plain assignment should work, no conversion is necessary.

Comment: If you need to join two byte slices together you can use the builtin [`append` function](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19.5#append).

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/YHyJ_PsuaBc

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
anyService := []byte{0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00}
host_uniq := []byte{0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04, 0x64, 0x13, 0x85, 0x78}
merged := append(anyService[:], host_uniq[:]...)
payload := gopacket.Payload(merged)

if err := gopacket.SerializeLayers(buffer, options, ethernetLayer, pppoe, gopacket.Payload(payload)); err != nil {
        pppoeLogger.Error("serialize-error")
}
```

Join the byte arrays and then convert it into the required type.

Comment: You can pass `merge` directly, no need to convert, **definitely not twice** (unless the `SerializeLayers `'s corresponding parameter type is not `gopacket.Payload` but something else, an interface implemented by Payload perhaps)